# phpDoc - Documenting for private members holding class instances

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have a class to document. There is a variable holding class instance which will be initialized in the constructor. I want to know how I can document (or put the tags) so that variable type is reflected properly.

I have done this so far:

```
/**
 * Holds the instance of ParseMessage class
 *
 * @access private
 * @var ParseMessage
 */
 private $_parse_message;
```

The Doc generated for this member looks like this:

```
Holds the instance of ParseMessage class
$_parse_message : **\ParseMessage**
```

I want to remove this '\' before the type of the variable.

Comment: I think the slash is there because of how phpDoc handles namespacing now.  Classes with a leading \ are in the global namespace.

Comment: @Crontab yes, my class is in global namespace. I will change the namespace, but there are too many files to do the same. Thanks for your help. Hope you could answer it directly so that I could accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading slash is probably there because of how phpDoc handles namespacing.  Classes with a leading \ are in the global namespace.  Apart from putting your class into its own namespace (as you said you'd do with this particular class), I couldn't find a setting that would make phpDoc omit the leading slash on global namespace classes.